# Indexing Query In MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql

I need to write a query which involves subquery and do indexing. So, I came up with a query to find the team name which has the Highest build up speed in a year:

```
SELECT CONCAT(team_long_name, ',', team_short_name) AS TeamName,
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) AS Year,
       buildUpPlaySpeed
FROM team JOIN
    team_attributes
    ON team.team_api_id = team_attributes.team_api_id
WHERE
    (buildUpPlaySpeed,team_attributes.date) in (SELECT 
            MAX(buildUpPlaySpeed),team_attributes.date
        FROM team_attributes
        WHERE team_attributes.date = team_attributes.date
        group by team_attributes.date)
ORDER BY date desc;
```

Indexes are present on date,team_api_id,buildUpPlaySpeed columns.

Any suggestions on how to reduce the cost further??

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Replace the correlated subquery with a join:

```
SELECT CONCAT (
    team_long_name
    ,','
    ,team_short_name
    ) AS TeamName
    ,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM [DATE]) AS Year
    ,buildUpPlaySpeed
FROM team
INNER JOIN team_attributes ON team.team_api_id = team_attributes.team_api_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(buildUpPlaySpeed) maxbuildup
        ,team_attributes.[DATE]
    FROM team_attributes
    WHERE team_attributes.[DATE] = team_attributes.DATE
    GROUP BY team_attributes.[DATE]
    ) x ON buildUpPlaySpeed = x.maxbuildup
    AND team_attributes.DATE = x.[DATE]
ORDER BY [DATE] DESC
;
```

and, for sanity's sake please don't  name columns "date" because that's used by SQL. Very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

try this also

```
SELECT CONCAT(team_long_name,',',team_short_name) AS TeamName,EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE) AS Year,buildUpPlaySpeed
FROM team
INNER JOIN team_attributes ON team.team_api_id = team_attributes.team_api_id
INNER JOIN ( SELECT MAX(buildUpPlaySpeed) maxbuildup,team_attributes.DATE FROM team_attributes
    WHERE team_attributes.DATE = team_attributes.DATE
    GROUP BY team_attributes.DATE  ) t1
where buildUpPlaySpeed = t1.maxbuildup AND team_attributes.DATE = t1.DATE ORDER BY DATE DESC;
```